# Swap (Drag Drop) not working in a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am working on sort of a puzzle game which looks something like in the below mentioned images

[image]

When I Swap content (Drag and Drop) just on the elements of mainDiv1, it is working fine.

[Swapping within mainDiv1]

[image]

It also works in the way when I Drag and Drop the elements (images) from mainDiv1 to mainDiv2.

[mainDiv1 to mainDiv2 image drag and drop on different divs] 
[image]

**PROBLEM:**

**1.** When I try to swap the elements in mainDiv2, it is not working. The element being dragged just disappears.

[image]

**2.** If I try to put these images back to the mainDiv1, I cannot do that too.

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong or if it is possible to call multiple functions on ondrag / ondrop.

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("src", ev.target.id);

}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();

var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
var srcParent = src.parentNode;
var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
}
function drop1(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("src");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


}
```

```css
#maindiv1
{
width: 48%;
height: fit-content;
background-color: #ffc7b1;
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
}
#div1
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
#div2
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: orange;
}
#div3
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
}
#div4
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: green;
}
#div5
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
#div6
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: violet;
}
#div7
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: indigo;
}
#div8 
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: chocolate;
}
#div9
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: teal;
}
#div10
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#div11
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: salmon;
}
#div12
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: plum;
}
#img1
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img2
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img3
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img4
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img5
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img6
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img7
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img8
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img9
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img10
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img11
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#img12
{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
#separator
{
width: 2%;
height: 500px;
background-color: white;
float: left;
}
#maindiv2
{
width: 48%;
height: fit-content;
background-color: #ffc7b1;
border: 1px solid;
float: left;
}
#odiv1
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: red;
}
#odiv2
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: orange;
}
#odiv3
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: yellow;
}
#odiv4
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: green;
}
#odiv5
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: blue;
}
#odiv6
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: violet;
}
#odiv7
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: indigo;
}
#odiv8 
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: chocolate;
}
#odiv9
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: teal;
}
#odiv10
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
#odiv11
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.9%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: salmon;
}
#odiv12
{
border: 1px solid;
width: 24.2%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
background-color: plum;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv1">
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/1.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img1" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/2.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img2" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/3.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img3" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/4.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img4" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/5.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img5" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/6.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img6" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/7.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img7" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/8.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img8" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/9.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img9" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/10.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img10" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/11.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img11" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
  <div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/12.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img12" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>
<div id="maindiv2">
  <div id="odiv1" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv2" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv3" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv4" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv5" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv6" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv7" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv8" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv9" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv10" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv11" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
  <div id="odiv12" ondrop="drop1(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### tl;dr:

Merge `drop` and `drop1` functions into one which handles both cases and apply it to all divs:

```
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
  if (src) {
    var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    if (tgt) {
      var srcParent = src.parentNode;
      ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
      srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
    } else {
      ev.currentTarget.appendChild(src);
    }
  }
}
```

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("src", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
  if (src) {
    var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    if (tgt) {
      var srcParent = src.parentNode;
      ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
      srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
    } else {
      ev.currentTarget.appendChild(src);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#maindiv1 {
  width: 48%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #ffc7b1;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#div1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}

#div3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div4 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#div5 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div6 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: violet;
}

#div7 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: indigo;
}

#div8 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

#div9 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: teal;
}

#div10 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#div11 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: salmon;
}

#div12 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: plum;
}

#img1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img4 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img5 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img6 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img7 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img8 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img9 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img10 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img11 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#img12 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#separator {
  width: 2%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#maindiv2 {
  width: 48%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #ffc7b1;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#odiv1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}

#odiv2 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
}

#odiv3 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#odiv4 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

#odiv5 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}

#odiv6 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: violet;
}

#odiv7 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: indigo;
}

#odiv8 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

#odiv9 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: teal;
}

#odiv10 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#odiv11 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: salmon;
}

#odiv12 {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.2%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: plum;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv1">
  <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/1.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img1" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/2.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img2" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/3.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img3" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/4.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img4" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/5.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img5" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/6.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img6" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/7.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img7" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/8.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img8" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/9.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img9" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/10.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img10" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/11.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img11" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
  <div id="div12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="images/12.gif" alt="Image not available" id="img12" ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>
<div id="maindiv2">
  <div id="odiv1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv8" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv9" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv10" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv11" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  <div id="odiv12" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

---

### proper answer:

Whenever you find yourself writing the same line of code twice, you should try to find a way to only [write it once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Taking the CSS, for example, instead of writing each property for each child, using that child as a selector, you should consider writing it only once, using the parent as selector:

```css
#maindiv1, #maindiv2 {
  width: 48%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #ffc7b1;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}

#maindiv1 > div, #maindiv2 > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24.9%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#maindiv1 > div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

#separator {
  width: 2%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#div1, #odiv1 { background-color: red; }

#div2, #odiv2 { background-color: orange; }

#div3, #odiv3 { background-color: yellow; }

#div4, #odiv4 { background-color: green; }

#div5, #odiv5 { background-color: blue; }

#div6, #odiv6 { background-color: violet; }

#div7, #odiv7 { background-color: indigo; }

#div8, #odiv8 { background-color: chocolate; }

#div9, #odiv9 { background-color: teal; }

#div10, #odiv10 { background-color: darkolivegreen; }

#div11, #odiv11 { background-color: salmon; }

#div12, #odiv12 { background-color: plum; }
```

The advantage being that, when you decide to make a change, you only change in one place and they all change. Like, for example, removing the hard-coded `200px` height and making them responsive.

---

The exact same principle applies to JavaScript. Rather than specifying the same function for the same event for each element, you should use a function/routine which goes through each of them and applies it:

```js
const leftDivs = document.querySelector('#maindiv1').querySelectorAll('div');
[...leftDivs].forEach(div => {
  div.ondrop = drop;
  div.ondragover = allowDrop;
});

const rightDivs = document.querySelector('#maindiv2').querySelectorAll('div');
[...rightDivs].forEach(div => {
  // `drop`, not `drop1`! We'll merge the two functions into one in next step
  div.ondrop = drop;
  div.ondragover = allowDrop;
});

const images = document.querySelector('#maindiv1').querySelectorAll('img');
[...images].forEach(img => {
  img.ondragstart = drag;
  img.draggable = true;
})
```

Obviously, you now need to remove the hardcoded `ondrop`, `ondragover`, `ondragstart` and `draggable` attributes, since you're applying them dynamically. Also note in the final working example (which you'll find at the end of the answer) I opted to rename all those functions to the exact attribute name they are being assigned to. It's clearer, hence easier to follow.

---

But, to have this working, instead of having two different functions handling each case:

- when you drop inside an element which already has an image
- when you drop inside an empty one

we should merge both into only one function:

```js
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var src = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
  var srcParent = src.parentNode;
  var tgt = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
  if (tgt) {
    ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(src, tgt);
    srcParent.appendChild(tgt);
  } else {
    // if no `tgt`, (currentTarget is empty), just place the image (src) into it
    ev.currentTarget.appendChild(src);
  }
}
```

Speaking of which, I find your naming conventions a bit confusing. One might think naming is not important but, in the long run, good naming conventions greatly reduce the time needed to understand (and modify) the code. Here's how I'd have written that function:

```js
function ondrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const image = document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("src"));
  // only proceed if `image` exists
  if (image) {
    const targetImage = ev.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    if (targetImage) {
      // define `imageParent` only for the case where it is used
      const imageParent = image.parentNode;
      ev.currentTarget.replaceChild(image, targetImage);
      imageParent.appendChild(targetImage);
    } else {
      ev.currentTarget.appendChild(image);
    }
  }  
}
```

---

Let's see it working.

I took the liberty to clean it up more, I renamed a few things and also changed the CSS to have some basic responsiveness - it's not perfect but, IMHO, it's better:

```js
const leftDivs = document.querySelector('#maindiv1').querySelectorAll('div');
const rightDivs = document.querySelector('#maindiv2').querySelectorAll('div');
[...leftDivs].concat([...rightDivs]).forEach(div => {
  div.ondrop = ondrop;
  div.ondragover = ondragover;
});

const images = document.querySelector('#maindiv1').querySelectorAll('img');
[...images].forEach(img => {
  img.ondragstart = ondragstart;
  img.draggable = true;
})

function ondragover(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function ondragstart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("imageId", e.currentTarget.id);
}

function ondrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const img = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData("imageId"));
  if (img) {
    const targetImg = e.currentTarget.firstElementChild;
    if (targetImg) {
      const imgParent = img.parentNode;
      e.currentTarget.replaceChild(img, targetImg);
      imgParent.appendChild(targetImg);
    } else {
      e.currentTarget.appendChild(img);
    }
  }  
}
```

```css
* {
  /* make all elements include border in width, so you don't have to use 24.9% */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#maindiv1,
#maindiv2 {
  width: 48%;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #ffc7b1;
  float: left;
}

#maindiv1>div,
#maindiv2>div {
  width: 25%;
  padding-bottom: 25%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#maindiv1>div img,
#maindiv2>div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

#separator {
  width: 2%;
  min-height: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#div1,
#odiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2,
#odiv2 {
  background-color: orange;
}

#div3,
#odiv3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#div4,
#odiv4 {
  background-color: green;
}

#div5,
#odiv5 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#div6,
#odiv6 {
  background-color: violet;
}

#div7,
#odiv7 {
  background-color: indigo;
}

#div8,
#odiv8 {
  background-color: chocolate;
}

#div9,
#odiv9 {
  background-color: teal;
}

#div10,
#odiv10 {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

#div11,
#odiv11 {
  background-color: salmon;
}

#div12,
#odiv12 {
  background-color: plum;
}
```

```html
<div id="maindiv1">
  <div id="div1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/200" alt="" id="img1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/200" alt="" id="img2">
  </div>
  <div id="div3">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/200" alt="" id="img3">
  </div>
  <div id="div4">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200/200" alt="" id="img4">
  </div>
  <div id="div5">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/241/200/200" alt="" id="img5">
  </div>
  <div id="div6">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/242/200/200" alt="" id="img6">
  </div>
  <div id="div7">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/243/200/200" alt="" id="img7">
  </div>
  <div id="div8">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/244/200/200" alt="" id="img8">
  </div>
  <div id="div9">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/247/200/200" alt="" id="img9">
  </div>
  <div id="div10">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/248/200/200" alt="" id="img10">
  </div>
  <div id="div11">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/249/200/200" alt="" id="img11">
  </div>
  <div id="div12">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/250/200/200" alt="" id="img12">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="separator"></div>
<div id="maindiv2">
  <div id="odiv1"></div>
  <div id="odiv2"></div>
  <div id="odiv3"></div>
  <div id="odiv4"></div>
  <div id="odiv5"></div>
  <div id="odiv6"></div>
  <div id="odiv7"></div>
  <div id="odiv8"></div>
  <div id="odiv9"></div>
  <div id="odiv10"></div>
  <div id="odiv11"></div>
  <div id="odiv12"></div>
</div>
```